# Which column type has support for lists in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sqlalchemy

I'm currently setting up a database for solar active regions and one of the columns is supposed to get the region number which, for now, I have declared in the following way:

```
noaa_number = sql.Column(sql.Integer, nullable=True)
```

However, since a new number may be assigned as the region evolves, which column type would better support a list to keep all the numbers that a given region is given? So instead of having an entry like:

```
noaa_number = 12443
```

I could have my result stored as:

```
#a simple entry
noaa_number = [12443]
#or multiple results
noaa_number = [12444,12445]
```

Where these elements in the list would be integers.

I was checking the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#generic-types) and the best idea I had was to place this column as a string and parse all the numbers out of it. While that would work just fine I was wondering if there is a better and more appropriate way of doing so.

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off with a separate table where you can map any number of region numbers to a given region. Have a look at this section of the docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#basic-relationship-patterns

Comment: Not really in this case (I think) because these numbers corresponds to a same data series which comprise an observation window. Therefore the properties I'm deriving and storing in other table will correspond to the regions given by both numbers.

Comment: Generally speaking, I agree with @SuperShoot that you should probably use a separate table. However, there are occasionally legitimate reasons to break the rules. If you are using a PostgreSQL backend, there is an [ARRAY type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY) you can use.

Comment: Even if the information on this column is not used to connect with the other tables?

Comment: @Chicrala In some specific cases you can use [array](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY). Example: `db.Column(postgresql.ARRAY(db.Integer()), )`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I'm using sqlite so I guess I would need to change for postgre. Anyway that answers the question I guess because it states which case arrays can be used. I think you should post it as an answer so I can give you the credits for it

Comment: @Chicrala thank you. good luck ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some cases you can use [array column](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY). This is really not bad way to store very specific data. Example:

```
class Example(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    my_array = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.Integer())

# You can easily find records:
# Example.my_array.contains([1, 2, 3]).all()
# You can use text items of array
# db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.Text())
```

Also you can use [CompositeArray](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sqlalchemy_utils/types/pg_composite.html) (*sqlalchemy_utils*) to use custom database types as array items. Example:

```
# let's imagine that we have some meta history
history = db.Column(
        CompositeArray(
            CompositeType(
                'history',
                [
                    db.Column('message', db.Text),
                ]
             )
        )
# example of history type:
CREATE TYPE history AS (
   message text
);
```

> Note! Not sure about **sqlite** but with **postgres** should works
>   fine.

Hope this helps.